# How to place a space at the end of cout

Tags: c++, windows, clion, cout

I need to know why c++ doesn't see the space just at the end of cout function.
I'm using CLion and C++ 23 (language_standart)

```
int main()

{

    string Item ;
    double Price ;
    int Quantity ;
    double Total ;

    cout << "Your item to buy : " ;
    getline(cin, Item) ;
    cout << "Price of the item : " ;
    cin >> Price ;
    cout << "Quantity of the item : " ;
    cin >> Quantity ;

    cout << endl ;

    Total = Price * Quantity ;

    cout << "Item : " << Item << endl ;
    cout << "Price : " << Price << endl ;
    cout << "Quantity : " << Quantity << endl ;
    cout << "Total is : " << Total << endl ;

}
```

When I run the code, it returns me

```
Your item to buy :**HereIsNoSpace**
**HereIsSpace**Price of the item : 
**HereIsSpace**Quantity of the item :
```

So I need to enter an Item just after ":" and not ": "

And as you can see probably my spaces somehow goes just after my input and passes to the next string

Comment: That seems like a problem with the terminal you're using (or you're not running the code you think you're running). What environment are you using when running?

Comment: I've seen that problem, but only with pre-standard C++.  In that era, I needed to have a `flush` of `cout` before `getline`.

Comment: What version of C++ are you using and what kind of terminal is this running in?

Comment: I'm using CLion and I don't actually know what exactly I should do with the terminal cause I don't use cmd in my case

Comment: Your code is all correct, so there must be something going on in your terminal. I'm not too sure what it could be, so hopefully someone else can chime in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently one of the workarounds is,
try doing the following: in Registry (Help | Find Action..., type Registry there) disable the run.processes.with.pty option and restart CLion. Does that help?
According to the response in CPP-12752 disabling PTY (without CLion restart, since the run.processes.with.pty option is not saved after CLion's restart - CPP-8395) helps.

Guys I've found the solve of this heck !

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

When you are using CLion, You can try disabling PTY (Help | Find Action > type "Registry" > open Registry > find and disable the run.processes.with.pty option)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mhbz6.png)